# $(document).on as live with find

Tags: jquery, find, document, live

I need to implement something like this

```
$(document).on('click','#test .foo',function(){
   alert('Good');
})
```

But I want to know if there is a way using `.find()`, like this

```
var $test = $('#test');
$(document).on('click',$test.find('.foo'),function(){
   alert('Good');
})
```

I'm using `$(document).on('click'` because '.foo' is dynamic

Thanks

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/on/ it seems that it only accepts the string of the selectors

Comment: Why would you need `.find()`?  By using the `$(document).on('click', selector, function(){// code});` syntax you are attaching the event to any existing or future instances of `.foo`.

Comment: yes I know, but I save the object in a variable before ($test), so I want to avoid to call to #test again. I just wanna know if there is a way with `find()` or something like that

Comment: why don't you just do `$test.on('click','.foo',function(){
       alert('Good');
    })`

Comment: because `.foo` is dynamic, if I add a new `foo` after the moment when the browser read the line, the new element will not trigger the click event